# Android studio Dolphin stuck in "analyzing"

Tags: java, android-studio

I have to invalidate caches every 5 minutes because of this, I just have the mandatory plugins and they are updated.

Most of the answers I have encounter mention the kotlin plugin but mine its updated as well and Im using java, not kotlin.

Answer (score 0):

Solved upgrading gradle from 4.1.2 to 7.3.0